# How to create two unique / primary keys with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have these tables :

```
public partial class user
{           
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class book
{          
    public string book-id{ get; set; }
    public string book_name{ get; set; }
}
```

and I'm looking to create a table to hold the user(id) and book (book_id) only to ignore the duplication .

For example: suppose the new table name is `Test` :

```
id ->1
book_id->1
id ->2
book_id->2
```

if I send again this values :

```
id ->1
book_id->1
```

it should not add them to database, so how to define that? What should the new class (Test) property / constraint be? And thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new class `Test` like this :

```
public class Test 
{
    [Key(Order=0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key(Order=1)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

By doing that, EF will create a table named `Test` in your database. That table will not allow duplication because we use composite key (UserId, BookId).

After that you need to add navigational propertiy `public ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }` in `Book` and `User`.